# Integral equation existance

Tags: integration

Explain why there is a unique continues function on $[0,3]$ that satisfies:

$$v(x)= \sin x + 1/4 \int_{0}^{3} e^{-x-y^2} v(y)\,dy$$

How can this be done?

Edit: there is a theorem that gives the result if sinx and $e^(-x-y^2)$ are continuous and $\lambda$ is small enough

Comment: $$v(x)= \sin x + 1/4 \int_{0}^{3} e^{-x-y^2} v(y)dy=\sin x + (1/4) e^{-x} \int_{0}^{3} e^{-y^2} v(y)dy$$

Comment: Is it always necessary to take one variable out?

Comment: No. If $e^{-y^2}v(y)$ is integrable in $[0, 3]$, then $v(x)$ is well defined in $[0, 3]$ and it is given by $v(x)=\sin x+(1/4)e^{-x}C$, where $C$ is a constant.
I do not understand the question. Why there is a problem on the existence of $v(x)$ or even on the uniqueness of it?

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both sides with respect to x we obtain:

$v'(x) = \cos x + \sin x - v(x) \implies v'(x) + v(x) = \cos x + \sin x$, and $v(0) = (1/4 \int_{0}^{3}e^{-y^2})v(y)dy$ . This is the $1$st order ODE with initial condition. So there is unique solution for $v(x)$.

Comment: please, please, **please** use MathJax.

Comment: @recursiverecursion: working on it asap.

Comment: [this](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols) has most of the basic commands, and there are many more guides out there. Just FYI.

Comment: @recursiverecursion: Thanks.